# Favicon doesn't show up in viewsource, or on images. (localhost chrome)

Tags: html, favicon, view-source

I'm currently creating a website, and I'm almost finished, but there's one problem. The favicon does not show up on view source, or on an image (in localhost, chrome). You see, I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this is just a bug. Thanks for the help.

[image]

See, no favicon will show up in view-source. This is the same with images. 
But if I hop over to google, they don't have this problem.

[image]

Is this problem happening just because I'm on localhost, and when I publish my site it will be fine?

Thank you.

. .

Also this is my code that I currently have for my favicon:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="./css/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./css/images/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./css/images/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="./css/images/favicons/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="./css/images/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./css/images/favicons/favicon.ico">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="test">
<meta name="application-name" content="test">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="./css/images/favicons/browserconfig.xml">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Comment: Have you named it `favicon.ico` and tossed it in the same directory as `index.html` ?   A lot of times the browser will pick it up automatically -- Without the need for the `favicon` html tag .. But then, it never hurts to add  `<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">`

Comment: I just put favicon.ico in the same directory as index.html but I'm still getting no favicon in view-source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please show us the `link rel` of your `head` tags to see if you are doing something wrong. I can edit my answer later if you edit your post.

*There is not much details about your question, so I will just try to tell you how to set a favicon for your website.*

Try deleting the one you made. Remove it from wherever you have placed it. Make sure you have named it **favicon.ico** and place it in your root folder of your website, where **index.html** is.

Then in the `head` section add the following code:

```
<link rel='icon' href='favicon.ico'>
```

You could also try to visit your localhost page with a private navigation. Sometimes favicons get messed up with browser's cache and history.

You could also check your favicon with real path (full URL) `localhost/mysite/css/favicons/favicon.ico` to check if it really exists there.

After discussing with the OP the problem happens only with the `view-source:` command, and the icon shows itself otherwise. So this is a normal behavior, as you can see even on google or whatever website the favicon disappears with the `view-source:` command.

Comment: Note: the `<link>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.